# svg element transition animation stuck when follow mouse move

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Following is my code, I hope make tooltip follow mousemove like [echart(render select svg) tooltip](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-stack)

but the result transition become stuck, how to make transition smooth

```
            var it: SVGTextElement
            var c: SVGGElement
            ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
                <svg>
                    <g ref={e => c = e}
                       onMouseMove={(ev: any) => {
                           var r = c.getBoundingClientRect()
                           var x = ev.clientX - r.x
                           var y = ev.clientY - r.y
                           it.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${x} ${y})`)
                       }}>
                        <rect x={0} y={0} width={300} height={300} fill={"transparent"} stroke={"black"}></rect>
                        <text ref={e => it = e} style={{transition: "all 0.5s ease"}}>tooltip</text>
                    </g>
                </svg>)
```

[image]

Comment: Please crate a functioning [mcve] snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

The mouse move handler should be attached to the SVG, not the tooltip.  As it is now, if you move the mouse quickly enough to escape the tooltip, the event will no longer fire.  And the tooltip will stop and appear to get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I find transition "ease" has a little stuck, use "linear" instead will make move smooth, following is my correct code

```
  var it: SVGTextElement
                var c: SVGGElement
                ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
                    <svg width={1000} height={500}>
                        <g ref={e => c = e}
                           onMouseMove={(ev: any) => {
                               var r = c.getBoundingClientRect()
                               var x = ev.clientX - r.x
                               var y = ev.clientY - r.y
                               it.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${x} ${y})`)
                           }}>
                            <rect x={0} y={0} width={1000} height={500} fill={"transparent"} stroke={"black"}></rect>
                            <text ref={e => it = e} style={{transition: "all 0.5s linear"}}>tooltip</text>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                )
```